# How to load symbol while debugging with GDB in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-remote, firmware

**Environment: WSL Ubuntu20.04 on Windows 10**

**GDB: gdb-multiarch (GNU gdb 9.2)**

**VSCODE version: 1.67.0**

I'm trying to debug with GDB on VSCODE.
If I use command-line in Ubuntu to connect with GDB server and load symboal to my target device. It works normally.

```
$gdb-multiarch main
$(gdb)target remote:2331
$(gdb)load
$(gdb)c
```

[Screenshot on Ubuntu command-line (Works normally)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge0AJ.jpg)

> However, I wanna do the same thing on VSCODE.

After modifying my *launch.json* file, the GDB debugger in VSCODE can only **"attach"** to my target device.  There is **no any symbol loaded**.  Here is my *launch.json*.

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "GDB Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main",
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "linux": {
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb-multiarch",
            "miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:2331"
        },
    }
]
```

Did I miss any propertey which needs to be filled in the configurations?

Thanks for any comments and helping:)

Answer (score 3):

You can open logs to see what happened:

```
"logging": {
    "moduleLoad": true,
    "engineLogging": true,
    "trace": true
},
```

There may be some configurations that affect the symbol load, such as `solib-search-path`, `sysroot`, you can check and add the configs in `setupCommands`

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
         "description": "Set sysroot ",
         "text": "set sysroot <path_to_sysroot>"
    },
    {
         "description": "Set solib",
         "text": "set solib-search-path <path_to_solib_search_path>"
    }
]
```